# Will migrating content types be possible?

Tags: 8, migrations, upgrading

I have a Drupal 7 site with 40 content types. When Drupal 8 will be released than I would like to migrate these content types.

Would this be possible, or would I have to create this content types from scratch?

Comment: Drupal 8 will have config migrations out of the box so you will be able to migrate content types easily.

Comment: 40 content-types? aren't they bit too many?

Comment: No such thing as too many @claws... depending on the use-case.  We have no idea what sokratis is using the website for.

Comment: this is a pretty good article about migrating nodes, but also includes Users and taxonomies: http://www.metaltoad.com/blog/migrating-nodes-drupal-7-to-drupal-8

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess the [best place to search for upgrade process](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/core%21UPGRADE.txt/8.0.x) is **UPGRADE.txt** file. Here you can find the step-by-step approach to follow in upgrading the site from Drupal 6/7 to Drupal 8.

Drupal 8 core will include a robust data migration API: https://drupal.org/node/2121299, part of the IMP initiative: https://groups.drupal.org/imp . Also you can check the recently updated list of modules that are included in Drupal 8 core: http://blog.merge.nl/2014/01/21/drupal-which-drupal-7-modules-went-into-drupal-core

Few of the links that you check:

1. Getting your site ready for Drupal 8: http://www.acquia.com/blog/getting-your-site-ready-drupal-8
2. Drupal 8 - Improved upgrade process: http://www.acquia.com/blog/d8migrate
3. Converting modules from Drupal 7 to Drupal 8:http://webchick.net/upgrade-modules-d8
4. Converting 7.x modules to 8.x: https://drupal.org/update/modules/7/8

Comment: UPGRADE.txt looks out of date right now, there won't be an upgrade path to Drupal 8, only a migration.

Comment: @Ben This might be a case, I need to check about this. Thanks for putting forward this point!!

Comment: what is the difference between `upgrade` & `migrate`?

Comment: @claws I believe the upgrade involved the moving from lower major version of drupal to the next upper available drupal version (e.g: Drupal 5/6 to Drupal 7), however the migration is moving/shifting from different framework (e.g: typo3 etc.) to Drupal

Comment: @AnkitAgrawal: But your definition doesn't make sense when I read `there won't be an upgrade path to Drupal 8, only a migration` in above comment. what does this statement mean?

Comment: @claws It is said because the Durpal 8 is completely different from current drupal versions (e.g. 6 or 7), it involved the integration of symphony framework components, MVC architecture, twig template engine etc.

Comment: @claws: it's not called a migration because the underlying technology is different, but because the process is different. An upgrade means that you take a D7 site and change it until it's a D8 site. If it fails, you have a broken site. That never worked well in D5 and D6 upgrades. A migration means that you set up a D8 site alongside your D7 site and migrate everything from one site to the other. The D7 site is not changed. You can keep improving your migration until you're happy with the result, and only then you switch from the D7 site to the D8 site.

Comment: **MAJOR VERSION MIGRATION
-----------------------
Upgrading from a prior major version of Drupal to Drupal 8.x is not possible.
The process now requires a migration to a Drupal 8.x site, using the Migrate
module in Drupal core.

Note that migration support in Drupal 8 is currently only partially implemented.**

Comment: @claws "Upgrade" would mean turning a D7 site into a D8 site by replacing code and running some scripts. A "migration" is installing a fresh D8 site separately from your D7 site and then pulling in the content and configuration.

Comment: Truth is that **upgrade** and **migrate** in Drupal 8 will be used as synonyms. Drupal 8 will offer migrations to upgrade sites. There is no upgrade path (as in DB schema alterations) but there are migration tools that let you move configuration and content from Drupal 6 and 7 8

Answer (score 1):

[Bas is right](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/177870/12010), but there is a lot of activity going on regarding this topic, so here is a more up-to-date (November 2015) answer:

Given the big difference in architecture between Drupal 7 and 8 there is no direct upgrade path, but Drupal 8 offers various *migrate* tools to *upgrade* sites from Drupal 6 and 7 to 8.

Using the core modules **Migrate** and **Drupal Migrate** and the contrib module **[Drupal Upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade)** you can migrate all 40 content types from Drupal 7 to 8.

These  modules allow you to migrate content types, content, comments, fields, vocabularies, terms and other Drupal 7 core entities and entity types (views, for example, cannot be migrated yet). [Read about Drupal 7 to 8 upgrades](https://www.drupal.org/project/migrate_upgrade).

With Drush and the contrib module [Migrate tools](http://drupal.org/project/migrate_tools) you can select which content types to migrate. [Read about executing a Drupal 7 to 8 upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/node/2257723).

Make sure you do not create any of the 40 content types before starting the upgrade. [Read more about preparing an upgrade](https://www.drupal.org/node/2350603).

Answer (score 0):

You can try to "upgrade" using the D8 core migrate module. Also install the contrib module migrate_plus. It allows you to convert custom content types, users, comments, taxonomy, etc. Most common fields should be covered. If you got something really custom going on, like a custom module, you'll also have to do some programming. But if you only used the essentials of D7, migrate might have you covered. In any case you'll have to rebuild a new site and migrate the content there, so it's not a painless solution in any sense.

Your most up to date documentation is found here: https://www.drupal.org/upgrade/migrate