# PreExistingConfigException: Configuration objects provided by progweb_migration already exist in active

Tags: 8, migrations

I'm playing with migrations from D7 to D8 and I've found that, when you register a module with a migration, if you disable it, next time you enable the module gets stuck on this:

```
[vagrant@devbox] /[...]/default $ drush en progweb_migration -y
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
PHP Warning:  Module 'imagick' already loaded in Unknown on line 0
The following extensions will be enabled: progweb_migration
Do you really want to continue? (y/n): y
exception 'Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException' with message 'Configuration objects[error]
(migrate.migration.custom_user) provided by progweb_migration already exist in active
configuration' in /www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Config/PreExistingConfigException.php:70
Stack trace:
#0 /www/drupal8/core/lib/Drupal/Core/Extension/ModuleInstaller.php(162):
Drupal\Core\Config\PreExistingConfigException::create('progweb_migrati...', Array)
#1 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(129):
Drupal\Core\Extension\ModuleInstaller->install(Array, true)
#2 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/commands/core/drupal/environment.inc(196):
drush_module_install(Array)
#3 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/commands/pm/pm.drush.inc(1120): drush_module_enable(Array)
#4 [internal function]: drush_pm_enable('progweb_migrati...')
#5 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(359):
call_user_func_array('drush_pm_enable', Array)
#6 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(210): _drush_invoke_hooks(Array,
Array)
#7 [internal function]: drush_command('progweb_migrati...')
#8 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/includes/command.inc(178):
call_user_func_array('drush_command', Array)
#9 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/lib/Drush/Boot/DrupalBoot.php(46): drush_dispatch(Array)
#10 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(76):
Drush\Boot\DrupalBoot->bootstrap_and_dispatch()
#11 /opt/drush7/vendor/drush/drush/drush.php(16): drush_main()
#12 {main}
```

It's like the migration is being registered but not de-registered. In D7 there is a method for that, but no luck so far trying in D8:

```
function progweb_migration_enable() {
  Migration::registerMigration('custom_user');
  Migration::registerMigration('custom_blog');

  Migration::registerMigration('ProgwebBlog');
  Migration::registerMigration('ProgwebUser');
}

function progweb_migration_disable() {
  Migration::deregisterMigration('custom_user');
  Migration::registerMigration('custom_blog');

  Migration::deregisterMigration('ProgwebBlog');
  Migration::registerMigration('ProgwebUser');

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4):

This is a core issue, not specific to Migrate. The problem is, config entities are copied into the active store when you enable your module but not deleted when you remove your module. This is what causes the errors when re-enabling your module.

I would highly suggest [Config Devel](https://drupal.org/project/config_devel) for developing migrations. It will allow you to synchronise your migrations back into the active store without re-installing.

Answer (score 2):

in case you need to uninstall the module (Ben answer is good), you'd need to add this to remove the config:

```
/**
 * hook_uninstall.
 */
function progweb_migration_uninstall() {
  db_query("DELETE FROM {config} WHERE name LIKE 'migrate.migration.progweb_custom_blog%'");
  db_query("DELETE FROM {config} WHERE name LIKE 'migrate.migration.progweb_custom_user%'");

  drupal_flush_all_caches();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with Drush.

First check the available migrations using: `drush config-list`

Then use `drush config-delete migrate.migration.custom_user` (from your example)